# Plug a function with currying into Spark UserDefinedFunction

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a function that works as expected

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray

def arrayContainsAny(s: Seq[String]): UserDefinedFunction = udf((xs: WrappedArray[String]) => !xs.toList.intersect(s).isEmpty)
```

I need to split the function from the `UserDefinedFunction` definition

I have have tried the following

```
// imports again
def _arrayContainsAny(s: Seq[String])(c: WrappedArray[String]): Boolean = !c.toList.intersect(s).isEmpty
def arrayContainsAny: UserDefinedFunction = udf[Boolean, WrappedArray[String], Seq[String]](_arrayContainsAny)
```

but it does not even compile.

The problem seems to be that I define the function as `udf[X, Y, Z]` and thus it expects a function `(Z, Y) => X` and not a `(Z)(Y) => X`

Does anyone know how to do this?

-- β

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**:

Using a method with two argument lists, when wrapping in a UDF you should pass the first argument and use `_` to get the resulting function:

```
def _arrayContainsAny(s: Seq[String])(xs: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) = xs.toList.intersect(s).nonEmpty

def arrayContainsAny(s: Seq[String]): UserDefinedFunction = {
  udf(_arrayContainsAny(s) _)
}
```

**Option 2**:

You can create a method that takes a `Seq[String]` and returns a function `WrappedArray[String] => Boolean`, then call that method when creating a UDF:

```
def _arrayContainsAny(s: Seq[String]) = 
  (xs: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => xs.toList.intersect(s).nonEmpty

def arrayContainsAny(s: Seq[String]): UserDefinedFunction = {
  udf(_arrayContainsAny(s))
}
```